# Import data com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException

Tags: java, mongodb, solr, database

When I try:

```
BasicQuery b = new BasicQuery("{db.processoDomain.find({})}");
```

Or:

```
 <document name="import">
  <entity processor="MongoEntityProcessor"
    query="{db.processoDomain.find({})}"
             collection="processoDomain"   
             datasource="bradescorobotjrsethemis"
             transformer="MongoMapperTransformer" name="processoDomain">
```

I got the following exception in solr:

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{db.processoDomain.find({})}
                               ^
    at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.read(JSON.java:301)
    at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parseObject(JSON.java:262)
    at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:227)
    at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:155)
    at com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(JSON.java:92)
    at com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(JSON.java:73)
```

Someone knows how to fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `{db.processoDomain.find({})}` seems to be wrong. Try this:

```
BasicQuery b = new BasicQuery("{}");
```

Or if query contains parameter, like this:

```
BasicQuery b = new BasicQuery("{ name : 'lukas' }");
```

Then you can run it like this:

```
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(new MongoClient("127.0.0.1"), "db_name");

    MongoOperations mongoOperation = (MongoOperations) mongoTemplate;

    YourDataClass result = mongoOperation.find(b, YourDataClass.class);
```

More infomations can be found in [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-query-document/)

Comment: Thanks @TTCC, this works. But I want to use more complex mongo query, like: db.processoDomain.aggregate([{
              $project: {
                'status': 1,
                'instancia': 1,
                'ano': 1,
                'numeroProcesso': 1,
                'partes': '$informacoesAdicionais.PARTES'
              }
            }])

Comment: Yes, if you are familiar with the core MongoDB console find() command, just put the “raw” query inside the new BasicQuery("{ xxxxxx }").

Comment: nice..do you have some simple example?

Comment: You can see here http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-query-document/

Comment: I'm having trouble to put aggregate function inside query in Solr data-config.xml